# How much ahead of normal PCs are super computers?

Tags: supercomputer

I'm just wondering given the rapid development in computing power, how many years ahead of say a $2000 PC are the world's fastest super computers.

So for example, how many years ago, would a super computer first had the same processing speed as today's  PC? And how many more years would we have to wait before a standard PC would be as powerful as today's supercomputer?

Comment: why was this question closed? It got 2 upvotes and it seemed to satisfy the FAQ.